# The prefect v1 server give me errors when starting

Tags: prefect

I am trying to start a prefect v1 server version 1.4.1. However, the graphql service does not work. In the docker logs, it is possible to see the following error:

```
tmp-graphql-1  | 
tmp-graphql-1  | Running Alembic migrations...
tmp-graphql-1  | 
tmp-graphql-1  | Could not upgrade the database!
tmp-graphql-1  | Error: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgres
```

Is anybody familiar with this error?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to [Prefect 2](https://docs.prefect.io/).